# Bulk MySQL to Elasticsearch transfer

Tags: mysql, logstash

I am using logstash and JDBC MySQL plugin to transfer tables from my MySQL database to Elasticsearch (ES) storage.

I have multiple tables in the mysql db, for example ex_1, ex_2, ex_3 etc... I want to select all the tables with 'ex_' in it and use that table name as the document_type in my ES. So if my table name is 'ex_1' it should create a document of type ex_1 in my ES.

I could do it for one table by hardcoding it and my logstash config file looks like this

```
#file: mdb.conf
input {
    jdbc {

            jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://linktomydb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"
            # The user/password of MySQL
            jdbc_user => "xyz"
            jdbc_password => "*****"
            jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"
            jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            statement => "SELECT * from ex_1"


     }
}
filter {  
   #to measure the ingestion rate
    metrics {
    meter => "events"
    add_tag => "metric"
  }
}

output {

if "metric" in [tags] {
    elasticsearch { 
    hosts => 'localhost'
    index => "logstash-metrics"
    }
}

else {
#stdout { codec => json_lines }
elasticsearch {
        #protocol => http
        index => "xyz"
        document_type => "ex_1"
        #document_id => "%{ex_rowid}"
        hosts => "localhost"
        workers => 4
        flush_size => 1000
    }
 }
}
```

I want to automate this process for 100s of tables present in mysql and want to make sure that the table name in the sql db is same as document type in ES storage. I am very new to logstash and ES in general. 
Any optimization suggestions are welcome too since this is a massive file transfer (about 100 million documents)
I would appreciate any help.
Thanks.